# Create JSON dict from HTML ids for Python (Flask)

Tags: jquery, python, html, json, dictionary

This is a bit of a design and a how-to question.

There is a series of `<divs>` on a page which were generated by Flask/Jinja.  The `divs` show images, and they have an `id` value which is a unique number like 2309201.  They also have other values in the html like `name`.

Since the user has the choice to remove an image `div` elements, I want to  send only the remaining `div` ids and other keys back to Python via Flask for further processing.

Assuming that there could be 1000+ ids, I want to create a dictionary and send this via POST to Flask.  How would I go about constructing a dictionary for each of these elements with JQuery/etc?

Comment: About design, using the html as a datastore is often considered a bad practice. Your data should already be in a list/object format in the first place. Then it's just a matter of serializing it.

Comment: Thanks spectras - when you say it should be in a list/object format already, how do you mean that?  It is originally stored as a dict and passed into the Jinja template.  But since it's editable on the front end, I need away to see the changes (i.e.: pass the revised dict back).  Is there an example/technology you have in mind for the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd see too possible approaches: 1) keep it in the html, but have your script parse the html into a JS object as soon as the page loads. From there, the JS object is the main reference, or 2) embed the data in JSON format in the page in addition to or instead of the html version (in the latter case, your JS must render dom nodes on the fly as soon as it loads). Be sure to properly escape your JSON if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class element to each div:

```
<div class="custom_image" id="uique_number"></div>
```

And then filter after this class and push all these ids to an array:

```
ids = [];
$('.custom_image').each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Maybe there is a better solution but I am quite sure this should work :)

Peace Yatekii